# Build primefaces from source with minimized resources

Tags: primefaces, build, resources, minimized

How to build primefaces from source and get minimized resources(css,js)?
I am using Primefaces 5.0, and use

```
mvn clean install
```

But the resources are not minimized.

```
primefaces.css/js
jquery-plugins.js
charts.css/js
editor.css/js
...
```

To make debug easier, it would be nice if there is a switch to turn on/off minimized resources during deploy.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at how they do it for the latest PF version (since that IS minimized) and do the same. And regarding the switch, well do the same as describe before but enhance it.

Comment: The blog(build from source) says mvn install, but resources are not minimized.

Comment: If  were that simple, it would have been minimized for 5.0. Look at how they 'confuigure'  it in the pom and what additional files are needed etc. Than do exactely that.

Comment: Do you have `maven-jsf-plugin` installed ?

Comment: yes. they will generate jsf related files. Its live demo has minimized version. But how to build it is not documented. Unfortunately I am not familiar with pom. thanks.